# WPF TabControl databinding behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, prism

I have a TabControl which is assigned a region ([PRISM](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) [region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)). i am instantiating views (User Controls) with their view models and adding those views to the region which will cause a tab item to be created which is the default region behavior for TabControls. now the problem is when the user switches to a different tab its like the previous tab(s) has lost their bindings and the validation error templates are gone.
What could be the problem ?

Comment: Could you post some code so I can see what might be going wrong here?

Comment: I am sorry because i don't know what part of the code could help but what i am doing is this: resolve the view along with its view model through DI then use IRegionManager.Add() and then IRegionManager.Activate(). the views are all of the same type which is a UserControl.

Comment: Did you tried to snoop your app?